# Java 8 - Base64 encoding generates "==" which can not be decoded

Tags: java, encoding, base64, decoding

I am currently working on a Server/Client system which should:

- send username and password to Server
- send a undefined large file to the Client

I want to encode these two steps with an AES and after that an Base64 encoding. The first step already works, but if I want to send the file, the Base64 encoding generates an "==" which causes the decoder to think this is the end of the file.

---

Class which is used for my coding

```
package tools;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AES {
    public static String cryptString(String toCrypt) {
        String ret = "";
        try {
            String keyStr = "key";
            byte[] key = keyStr.getBytes("ASCII");
            MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            byte[] crypt = cipher.doFinal(toCrypt.getBytes("ASCII"));
            Base64.Encoder myencoder = Base64.getEncoder();
            String crypted = myencoder.encodeToString(crypt);
            ret = new String(crypted).trim();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return ret;
    }

    public static String decryptString(String crypted) {
        String ret = "";
        try {
            String keyStr = "key";
            byte[] key = keyStr.getBytes("ASCII");
            MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            Base64.Decoder myDecoder = Base64.getDecoder();
            byte[] encrypt = myDecoder.decode(crypted.trim().getBytes("ASCII"));
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            ret = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypt)).trim();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

---

The error which is thrown if I try to decode the string in the Client

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input byte array has incorrect ending byte at 856
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Unknown Source)
    at tools.AES.decryptString(AES.java:39)
```

---

I am using eclipse between.
If I use only a Message Like "Access Denied" there isn't a problem, too.

Comment: Your code works without problems on Java 8.

Comment: Yes it does.
But If I send larger files / messages this error has occured.
At this very moment I've got a similar problem with the AES crypting.

for small messages it works, but for larger ones it throws an BadPaddingException, wich I don't know to fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Encoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html).

```
Base64.Encoder myencoder = Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding();
```

Using withoutPadding yields a new Encoder not writing `=` pad chars at the end of file.